# Thermodynamics of free and independent electron gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

$\let\vec\mathbf$
Problem 2 in Ashcroft and Mermin's second chapter asks to use the relations
\begin{eqnarray}
c_V &=& \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)_n = T\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T}\right)_n \label{e1}\tag{1} \\
f(\varepsilon) &=& \frac{1}{e^{(\varepsilon - \mu)/(k_BT)} + 1} \label{e2}\tag{2} \\
u &=& \int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}\varepsilon(\vec{k})f(\varepsilon(\vec{k})) \label{e3}\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}
and the third law of thermodynamics $s \rightarrow 0$ as $T \rightarrow 0$ to show
\begin{equation}\label{e4}\tag{4}
s = -k_B\int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}[f\ln f + (1 - f)\ln(1 - f)].
\end{equation}

When I attempt to use equations \eqref{e1} to \eqref{e3} I end up getting an extra term in my expression for $s$. I believe that is because I am not using the condition $s \rightarrow 0$ as $T \rightarrow 0$ correctly. Can someone please point out where I could be going wrong?

Here's is a sketch of my solution. From
\begin{equation}
c_V = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)_n
\end{equation}
and equations \eqref{e2} and \eqref{e3} I get
\begin{equation}\label{e5}\tag{5}
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\right)_n = \frac{1}{k_BT^2}\int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}\varepsilon(\vec{k})(\varepsilon(\vec{k}) - \mu)\frac{e^{(\varepsilon - \mu)/(k_BT)}}{(e^{(\varepsilon - \mu)/(k_BT)} + 1)^2}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}\label{e6}\tag{6}
\left(\frac{\partial s}{\partial T}\right)_n = \frac{1}{k_BT^3}\int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}\varepsilon(\vec{k})(\varepsilon(\vec{k}) - \mu)\frac{e^{(\varepsilon - \mu)/(k_BT)}}{(e^{(\varepsilon - \mu)/(k_BT)} + 1)^2}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}\label{e7}\tag{7}
s = \int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}\int dT\frac{\varepsilon(\vec{k})(\varepsilon(\vec{k}) - \mu)}{k_bT^3}\frac{e^{(\varepsilon - \mu)/(k_BT)}}{(e^{(\varepsilon - \mu)/(k_BT)} + 1)^2}.
\end{equation}
If we introduce the variable
\begin{equation}\label{e8}\tag{8}
x = \frac{\varepsilon - \mu}{k_BT}
\end{equation}
then \eqref{e7} becomes
\begin{equation}\label{e9}\tag{9}
s = -k_B\int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon - \mu}\int dx \frac{xe^x}{(e^x + 1)^2}
\end{equation}
The $x$-integral is
\begin{equation}\label{e10}\tag{10}
\int dx \frac{xe^x}{(e^x + 1)^2} = \frac{xe^x}{e^x + 1} - \ln(e^x + 1) = f\ln f + (1 - f)\ln(1 - f)
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{eqnarray}
s &=& -k_B\int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}\frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon - \mu}[f\ln f + (1 - f)\ln(1 - f)] \\
 &=& -k_B\int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}[f\ln f + (1 - f)\ln(1 - f)] + \\ 
 & & \frac{\mu}{T}\int\frac{d\vec{k}}{4\pi^3}\frac{k_BT}{\epsilon - \mu}[f\ln f + (1 - f)\ln(1 - f)] \label{e11}\tag{11}.
\end{eqnarray}

I know that I haven't used third law of thermodynamics so far but neither do I know how to use it correctly to get rid of the extra term in \eqref{e11}.

Comment: maybe think about $S=-k_B \sum_i p_i \ln p_i$ if you have heard of that

Comment: @AndrewSteane I can use that but I want to know the role of the third law of thermodynamics in the derivation.

Comment: You did use the third law of thermodynamics to say that $S(T)=\int_0^TdT'\frac{\partial S}{\partial T'}$

Comment: You should be much more careful with the bounds of the $T$ and $x$ integrals (mainly use bounded integrals). In particular, for different values of $k$, $x$ will be positive or negative. I don't know if this solves your problem, but it might

Comment: Hi, are you studying Ashcroft and Mermin right now? Would love to work together on problems etc. if you are!

Comment: Yes, I will be very happy to study with you.

Comment: @EE18, you can reach out to me on dr.amey.joshi@gmail.com.